# Prefetch Count when using RabbitMQ clustering

Tags: concurrency, rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm using RabbitMQ(3.8.14 ver) and Masstransit(8.0.1 ver).
I need to guarantee each message given Ack, then another packet starts consuming. (actually, in my queue, I generate a unique incremental key, then I must ensure at the moment only a packet gets consumed.) 
this is noticeable to say, my rabbit MQ was configured as a cluster with three nodes.

for that, I configured the prefetch count with a "1" value.
but in the load test before giving Ack for the first message, the second message was consumed. despite descriptions given about "prefetch count".
[image]

sample code:

```
public class Caller
{
    ///ctor inections
  private static int number= 0;
   
    public async Task publish()
    {
        await _publishEndpoint.Publish(new GeneratedChipsEvent { messageNumber = ++number}); ;
    }
 }


public class GeneratedChipsEvent
{
    public int messageNumber { get; init; }
}


public class GeneratedChipsEventConsumer : IConsumer<GeneratedChipsEvent>
{
       
    ///ctor inections

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<GeneratedChipsEvent> context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"starting consuming the messsage:{context.Message.messageNumber}");
        await Task.Delay(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
        _logger.LogInformation($"ending consuming the messsage:{context.Message.messageNumber}");
    } }
```

logs in my local machine(non-cluster) that wait for ack first message, then starts consuming the second message:

> [10:06:08 INF] starting consuming the messsage:1
> [10:06:11 INF] ending consuming the messsage:1
> [10:06:11 INF] starting consuming the messsage:2
> [10:06:14 INF] ending consuming the messsage:2
> [10:06:14 INF] starting consuming the messsage:3
> [10:06:17 INF] ending consuming the messsage:3

logs in the server(as a cluster), that don't wait for ack first message:

> [10:16:33 INF] starting consuming the messsage:1
> [10:16:33 INF] starting consuming the messsage:2
> [10:16:33 INF] starting consuming the messsage:3
> [10:16:36 INF] ending consuming the messsage:1
> [10:16:36 INF] ending consuming the messsage:2
> [10:16:36 INF] ending consuming the messsage:3

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a question here, but you might explain the problem you're seeing, indicate which version of MassTransit you're using, and perhaps some logs from when it happened.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running three instances of your service, you'll see three messages consumed at a time, one on each instance. The prefetch count is per instance, it is not a global lock.

To only have one consumer active at a time, that can be specified on the receive endpoint configurator:

`e.SingleActiveConsumer = true;`

Comment: can I use "single active consumer" for the purpose of 'global lock'? if can't, then how can I do that?

Comment: See the update above.